# Large Numpy array handler, numpy data procession, memmap funciton mapping

Tags: python, file, numpy

Large numpy array (over 4GB) with nyp file and memmap function

I was using numpy package for array calculation where I read https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/neps/npy-format.html

In "Format Specification: Version 2.0" it said that, for .npy file, "version 2.0 format extends the header size to 4 GiB".

My question was that:

1. What was header size? Did that mean I could only save numpy.array of sizeat most 4GB array into the npy file? How large could a single array go?

I also read https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html
where it stated that "Memory-mapped files cannot be larger than 2GB on 32-bit systems"

2. did it mean numpy.memmap's limitation was based on the memory of the system? Was there anyway to avoid such limitation?
3. Further, I read that we could chose the dtype of the array, where the best resolution was "complex128". Was there any way to "use" and "save" elements with more accuracy on a 64 bit computer?(more accurate than complex128 or float64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous header size field was 16 bits wide, allowing headers smaller than 64KiB. Because the header describes the structure of the data, and doesn't contain the data itself, this is not a huge concern for most people. Quoting the notes, "This can be exceeded by structured arrays with a large number of columns." So to answer the first question, header size was under 64KiB but the data came after, so this wasn't the array size limit. The format didn't specify a data size limit.

Memory map capacity is dependent on operating system as well as machine architecture. Nowadays we've largely moved to flat but typically virtual address maps, so the program itself, stack, heap, and mapped files all compete for the same space, in total 4GiB for 32 bit pointers. Operating systems frequently partition this in quite large chunks, so some systems might only allow 2GiB total for user space, others 3GiB; and often you can map more memory than you can allocate otherwise. The memmap limitation is more closely tied to the operating system in use than the physical memory.

Non-flat address spaces, such as using distinct segments on OS/2, could allow larger usage. The cost is that a pointer is no longer a single word. PAE, for instance, supplies a way for the operating system to use more memory but still leaves processes with their own 32 bit limits. Typically it's easier nowadays to use a 64 bit system, allowing memory spaces up to 16 exabytes. Because data sizes have grown a lot, we also handle it in larger pieces, such as 4MiB or 16MiB allocations rather than the classic 4KiB pages or 512B sectors. Physical memory typically has more practical limits.

Yes, there are elements with more precision than 64 bit floating point; in particular, 64 bit integers. This effectively uses a larger mantissa by sacrificing all of the exponent. Complex128 is two 64 bit floats, and doesn't have higher precision but a second dimension. There are types that can grow arbitrarily precise, such as Python's long integers (long in python 2, int in python 3) and fractions, but numpy generally doesn't delve into those because they also have matching storage and computation costs. A basic property of the arrays is that they can be addressed using index calculations since the element size is consistent.